# Spring Boot JMS integration

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I am going through the [Spring Boot JMS guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms/). Here the `JMSTemplate` is initialized in the `main` method using `context.getBean`. How can I initialize `JMSTemplate` outside the `main` method (i.e. in a separate class)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a separate config class for creating your jms configuration as follows :

```
@Configuration
public class JmsConfig {

@Bean
public MessageConverter messageConverter() {
  MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
  converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
  converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
  return converter;
 }
}
```

Once you are done with configuration you can fetch the JMSTemplate bean from any class, for example ;

```
@Component
public class HelloSender {

  private final JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

   public HelloSender(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate) {
   this.jmsTemplate = jmsTemplate;
  }
}
```

Here your JMSTemplate bean is getting autowired using constructor injection.

Comment: you are welcome, please be so kind and upvote so that it could become useful for others

Comment: I did upvote but got below message. Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.